# How to Use Loop in R to Return Maximum Values for Each Category?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Table 1 is a sample of the data set I have. As you can see, John Doe has the highest frequency of A's, Mark Twain the highest frequency of B's, Ally Mahoney has the highest frequency of C's.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1JoN.png)

Table 2 is what I'd like to achieve (a table with only the person with the highest frequency and their corresponding classification):

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sg7j.png)

Would it be possible to do this using a loop function? E.g. go through each of the unique classifications, identify which one has the highest frequency, and print the associated name? How would this work in code?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. don't show images of the data but use the output of `dput`. In general, have a look at `dplyr` and there the `group_by` and `summarise` functions, so you don't need loops

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment - but I am interested in using a loop to achieve this. Would you be able to explain how this is possible with loops? @starja

Comment: Right, but in this case you should make your post more specific so that SO members can help better. Unless you have specific needs, R common lore has it that you should avoid loops. This is a general rule of thumb that has exceptions, however.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of R lies in that you can easily obtain such results *without* any loop by applying sorting principles and fast orderings.
I usually use the `data.table` framework, which noticeably shrinks boilerplate for such things.
Below is your code in this framework:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

# Your data
CF <- c(2,1,4,3,16,13,3)
Person <- c("John Doe", "Emily Bronte", "Mark Twain", "Jake Law", "Ally Mahoney", "Ellie Davies", "Bob Knight")
Classification <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")

# The data table
DT <- data.table(Classification, Person, "Classification Frequency" = CF)

# ordering it by classification frequency:
setorderv(DT, "Classification Frequency", -1)

# now, group by classification letter, and in each group, select the first 
# occurrence of Person. This will correspond to the Person with highest 
# classification frequency, as we just sorted:

DT[ , .(Person = Person[1]), keyby = Classification]

#
#   Classification       Person
# 1:              A     John Doe
# 2:              B   Mark Twain
# 3:              C Ally Mahoney
```

It is just a one-liner once the data has been entered and sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a loop:

```
CF <- c(2,1,4,3,16,13,3)
Person <- c("John Does", "Emily Bronte", "Mark Twain", "Jake Law", "Ally Mahoney", "Ellie Davies", "Bob Knight")
Classification <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")

data <- data.frame(
  CF = CF,
  Person = Person,
  Classification = Classification
)

for (i in unique(data$Classification)) {
  temp <- data[data$Classification %in% i, ]
  index <- which.max(temp$CF)
  print(temp$Person[index])
}

[1] "John Does"
[1] "Mark Twain"
[1] "Ally Mahoney"
```

But there are nicer possibilities out there, see e.g. @user12030145's answer.